# Integral Function in R

Tags: r, function, numerical-methods, integral, numerical-integration

I have defined the following function in R

[image]

(where `a` is a given constant and [image] is a known function) but when I try to compute the values of it I get some pretty weird numbers.

I should point out that, in order to compute the values of `f(s)`, I have actually solved the integral analytically before hand hence, in reality, my user defined function in R doesn't have to compute that integral. I would like to see whether I have made a mistake in my R code (since I'm pretty sure I solved the integral correctly) by comparing my values with those I would get If I were to solve the integral numerically. I have read the documentation for `integrate` but it doesn't seem to do what I need: am I correct? Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
# Function
f=function(s,a,lambda){
   1-exp(-integrate(lambda,lower=a,upper=s,rel.tol=1e-5)$value)   
}

# Check
f(s=1,a=0,lambda=function(t) t)
1-exp(-1/2)
```

Some **important warnings**:

1) `integrate` needs a vectorized function to work with, you will need to adapt your `lambda`function to satisfy this constraint (for example by using `lambda.vect=function(t) sapply(t,function(tt) lambda(tt))`). Recall what happens here:

```
f(s=1:2,a=0,lambda=function(t) 1) # Use rep(1,length(t)) instead
```

2) If the function $\lambda$ is too wiggly then you may need to tune the arguments `subdivisions` and `abs.tol` appropiately, see the documentation.

3) `f` is not a vectorized function, so it will return a single value no matter if you pass an vector to `s`. To vectorize it, adapt solution on 1).

Comment: so `integrate` **is** what I'm looking for... I did read the documentation but I was under the impression that I would have had to make some kind of indented function to make it work. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Yes, actually the question was not so clear since you did not post the code, so it was unclear for whether you have tried or not `integrate`. Anyway, that piece of code hopefully should do the work ;)